# How to transfer installed package from old admin to new admin in salesforce

Tags: managed-package, administration

Hi I am new admin trying to transfer change the installed package from old admin who resigned the company to my name. How can I do that without uninstalling/ effecting the current business process. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Managed packages aren't really "owned" as such by an admin. There might be resources like scheduled jobs that execute as the admin, or OAuth connections authorized as their user. Could you please [edit] your post to share what kind of specific managed-package resources you're concerned about?

Comment: Hi David: I heard that once the account gets deactivated you can't make changes to the packages. Is that true? If not, what might the problem be? Currently the salesforce org has installed packages like Slack, Distribution Engine, zoom etc Software. These packages are installed by the old admin user using their own credentials. 

How can I switch OAuth connections that are permitted with the old user to the new one as well? thank you.

Comment: No, that general statement is not true. It's important to be specific about the resources you're concerned with. Again, please [edit] your post.